# How change column in laravel model?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two columns in laravel: `ip` and `hostname`. In all blade I write `$server->ip`. I need do in models this condition:

`$server->ip = $server->hostname !== NULL ? $server->hostname : $server->ip`

How I can do this in model?

And when I write `$server->ip` I need get values from this condition..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model add this function:

```
public function getIpAttribute()
{
    return $this->hostname !== NULL ? $this->hostname : $this->ip;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide what version of laravel you are using - but what I think you are looking for exists in most recent versions. This can be accomplished with a mutator on the Server eloquent model.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators

```
class Server extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the server identity.
     *
     * @return String
     */
    public function getServerIdentityAttribute()
    {
        return $this->hostname !== NULL ? $this->hostname : $this->ip;
    }
}
```

After defining the attribute, you will be able to access it with `$server->server_identity;`